# How do I get the period/amplitude/sine function from a Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

If I have my list peaks from a Fourier transform of a list of values, how can I find the period / amplitude / function approximation of that original list of values from those peaks? I have seen variations of this question elsewhere on SE, and the responses are comprehensive, but they do not appear to simply and directly answer the original question.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an interactive version... put the signal you want analyzed in sig, and choose how many points you want to use in the reconstruction.

```
sig = Table[TriangleWave[5 t], {t, 0, 1, 0.01}];
lenSig = Length[sig];
Manipulate[Module[{},
  fftY = Fourier[sig, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
  mag = Abs[fftY]/lenSig; phase = Arg[fftY];
  ordMag = Ordering[mag, All, GreaterEqual];
  rec = Total[Table[mag[[ordMag[[k]]]] 
               Cos[2 Pi (ordMag[[k]] - 1) (n - 1)/lenSig + phase[[ordMag[[k]]]]], 
                    {k, 1, numTerms}, {n, 1, lenSig}]];
  GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[{Tooltip[mag, "not used"], 
      Tooltip[Thread[{ordMag[[1 ;; numTerms]], 
         mag[[ordMag[[1 ;; numTerms]]]]}], "used in reconstruction"]},
      Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotLabel -> "Fourier Transform of Signal", 
      PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Black, PointSize[0.015]}}], 
     ListLinePlot[{Tooltip[sig, "signal"], Tooltip[rec, "reconstruction"]}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Signal (blue) and Reconstructed Signal (brown)", 
     PlotRange -> All, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]}, ImageSize -> 800]],
 {{numTerms, 5, "number of terms in reconstruction"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

To see where the reconstruction comes from: first, choose the `numTerms` largest of the peaks for reconstruction. The frequencies of these peaks and the phases go inside the Cos term. The magnitudes of the peaks multiply the Cos term. The `Total` command sums them up.

Comment: Thank you so much... but I am completely lost. How did you make that reconstruction? I don't understand where the reconstruction comes from.

Comment: I've added a few words about how the reconstruction is done.